# Merge double linked list in C language

Tags: c, merge

Merge the two linked list in C language.

I tried to merge the two sorted double linked list. When I ran my code with different inputs, sometime the code just crushed with  EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I can't figure out why, the code seemed perfect for me and I use the similar way to merge two single linked list, it worked.
   Can someone explain? Thanks!

```
   #include <stdio.h>  

   #include <stdlib.h>

   typedef struct Node
   {

    struct Node* prior;

    struct Node* next;

    int value;

   }Node,*list;

  list create_list()
  {          

      list head = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));

      if(!head) exit(-1);

      list tail;

      tail=head;

      printf("Please enter the length of double linked list:\n");

      int len;

      scanf("%d",&len);

       for(int i=0;i<len;i++)

        {

         list new = (list)malloc(sizeof(Node));

         printf("Please enter the value of node:\n");

         int val;

         scanf("%d",&val);

         new->value=val;

         tail->next = new;

         new->prior=tail;

         tail=new;
    }
    return head;
  }

   list merge_list(list a, list b)
   {

      if(a==NULL||b==NULL) exit(-1);

      list p=(list)malloc(sizeof(Node));

      list l=p;

      while(a&&b)
      {

         if(a->value<=b->value)
          {

            p->next = a;

            a->prior=p;

            p=a;

            a=a->next;

           }
      else
      {

           p->next = b;

          b->prior=p;

          p=b;

          b=b->next;

      }
    }
   if(a!=NULL)

     {

        p->next=a;

        a->prior=p;
    }

    if(b!=NULL)
    {

      p->next=b;

      b->prior=p;

     }

    return l;
}

    int main() {

     list l = create_list();

     l=l->next;

     list m = create_list();

     m=m->next;

    list n =merge_list(l,m);

     n=n->next;

    while(n)
   {

       printf("%d\n",n->value);

       n=n->next;
   }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Format your code properly. Fix indentation and don't have a newline every other line. To much scrolling.

Comment: Please fix your spacing and indenting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You have multiple copies of the code for inserting a node. Move that into a function to save on error-searching effort and improve readability.

Comment: I did the non-obvious part of markdown fixing for you. You please do the next step, remove empty lines, apply a consistent indentation (including to remove the leadding blanks, which might seem to have been introduced by me).

Comment: I am sorry I still have some problems with the format. No indenting, but the empty lines are removed.

Comment: Why the command+k key doesn't work for me and why I have to  press space at the end of each line in order to separate two lines.

Comment: typedef of `list` to be a pointer to the struct is a real bad idea - don't typedef pointers

Comment: Are you aware that the editing history of this question does not show any edit by you? Try this link [edit]. A newline in prose is ignored, a newline following two blanks makes a newline in output. In code (starting with four blanks in each line, as I did for you), newlines act as expected. Just delete the completely empty lines and save the edits.

Comment: It is possible that the ctrl+k key seems not to work for you, because I used it to put your code into code formatting, using it again will undo that. My edit made sure that there are AT LEAST 4 blanks at the start of each code line. The more tedious job to make sure that only a suitable multiple of 4 blanks are used I leave for you.

Comment: In case you did the empty line removal and then gave up on the edit because of the ctrl+k behaviour, please do the two steps separatly. First delete the empty lines, then save the edit. Then work on indentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in `create_list` you do not initialize `new->next` with `NULL`.

From this error it makes no sense in `merge_list` to compare pointers with `NULL`.

Comment: Ok The code works now. But I am so confused. What is the difference between new-> next=NULL; and just simply doing nothing? And then why I created the two lists successfully??

Comment: @Liu malloc'ed memory are uninitialized so you need to do all initialization yourself. If you do nothing then `new->next` (or in the end `tail->next`) may hold any value. That is **not** what you want! For a linked list you always want `tail->next` to be NULL

Comment: @Liu You simply do not construct the list correctly. Your need to keep somehow the information about the length of the list. Because you do not keep explicitly the number of elements, you need to indicate somehow where the list ends -- either using the NULL pointer or by using a sentinel element (a singleton that means the end). If you used calloc instead of malloc, you would not need to initialize `new->next` with NULL, as calloc does the job.

Comment: then why I can print the link list if I just call create_list function()?
And in single linked list, I still didn't state new -> next = NULL, the code still works , why??

Answer (score 0):

The most important bug (i.e. no initialization of `new->next`) has already been addressed by the answer from @alinsoar.

However, there are other bugs in your code that a) cause memory leaks and b) cause the linked list to be incorrect.

In `main` you have:

```
 list l = create_list();
 l=l->next;  // Why ......
```

Why do you "throw away" the first element like that? That's a memory leak! And further it means that `l->prio` is not NULL as it should be!

I know it's because your `create_list` inserted a phony node in the start. But don't just fix it by throwing the node away. Fix the function instead.

Do something like this:

```
list create_list()
{          
  list head = NULL; // Do not use malloc here - just assign NULL
  list tail = NULL;

  printf("Please enter the length of double linked list:\n");
  int len;
  scanf("%d",&len);

  for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
  {
     list new = malloc(sizeof(Node));  // do not cast malloc
     new->next = NULL;                 // set the next pointer

     printf("Please enter the value of node:\n");
     int val;
     scanf("%d",&val);
     new->value=val;

     // Add the node to the end
     new->prior=tail;
     if (tail)
     {
         tail->next = new;
     }
     else
     {
         // First element so update head
         head = new;
     }
     tail=new;
  }
  return head;
}
```

With this code you don't get an extra element in the start and you can delete the code `l=l->next;` in main. Similar changes applies to `merge_list` but I'll leave that to you as an exercise.

In the end your `main`should only be:

```
int main() {
    list l = create_list();
    list m = create_list();
    list n =merge_list(l,m);
    while(n) {
        printf("%d\n",n->value);
        n=n->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cool! But I haven't figured out the most important bug yet! Can you further explain it to me??

Comment: @Liu I'm not sure what you mean... The most important bug is that you never did: `new->next = NULL;`

Comment: But isn't tail->next = new; enough?? And why my code works in single linked list without new->next=NULL;? Thank you!

Comment: @Liu No, `tail->next = new;` You explicit need to initialize `new->next`

Comment: I have another question, do I need to free those lists I created at the end of main method?

Comment: @Liu Well... all modern OS (i know) will do it for you when the program terminates so in shouldn't matter. However, most programmers consider it good practice to do it yourself. So... yes, I would write a `free_list` function and call it on all three lists

Comment: I wrote a function like free_list, and I passed then as pointers, and I freed the lists. As we know you can only modify the value of a pointer not the address . Why I can free those lists, if I pass then as pointers rather than double pointers?

Comment: @Liu Because you don't "free the pointer" - you "free the memory the pointers point to"

Comment: Oh！That explains! Thank you so much!

Comment: If I can free the memory the pointer I  points to in the function, then why I can't change the memory the pointer points to??

Comment: @Liu You **can** change the memory the pointer **points to**. The code does exactly that - several times e.g. `new->value=val;`

Comment: yes I can but only in the function to which I pass the pointer to. After the function is done, the pointer reverted back to its original memory. Right?

Comment: @Liu You confuse the pointer itself and the memory the pointer **points** to. These are different things. The pointed to memory can be changed in a function and will remain changed when the function return. The value of the pointer however can not be changed so that it is still changed when the function returned.